# Entity extraction in Solr

Tags: search, indexing, solr, lucene, lucidworks

**Use case**

Say 2 documents have been indexed in Solr. And one of the field is - desc_s (string) as below :

> Doc : Doc1
>
> Field : desc_s
>
> Value : XYZ buys ABC for 2.4 billion USD

---

> Doc : Doc2
>
> Field : desc_s
>
> Value : DEF sells $3.4 billion house

**Output**

What we need to do is to extract entities like ABC,XYZ,PQR and also identify buy/sell signal from desc_s and create tag against it

> New field is created - *tags*
>
> *tags*(for Doc1) - ABC,XYZ (string)
>
> *tags*(for Doc2) - DEF(string)

and create another field called "signal" which will have Buy/Sell as facet

```
Signal
  |
  Buys 
  |
  |___ABC
  |___XYZ
  Sells
  |
  |___DEF
```

**What have I tried ?**

*For extracting entities ABC,XYZ,DEF tags - it's working fine*

I have added the following analyzer (in schema.xml) to identify the tags and extract them in 1 field.

```
<field name="tags" type="key_phrases" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="desc_s" dest="key_phrases"/>
<fieldType name="key_phrases" class="solr.TextField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
<analyzer>
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KeepWordFilterFactory"
            words="tags.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Now , here - tags.txt contains all entities (like ABC,DEF,PQR,XYZ..etc) where the analyzer will lookup and populate desired entities in tags field.

Followed [this](https://lucidworks.com/blog/2013/06/27/poor-mans-entity-extraction-with-solr/) for entity extraction

Need some suggestions/approach on how to build buy/sell facet for the same.
For now, we can consider the desc_s will have only buys/sells in their text.

Comment: What kinda of facets you want? show an example please

Comment: Signal--buys--sells.....In buys - it will have ABC and XYZ and another facet sells which will have DEF ... I have shown the example in the output section of my post ..